# How to map fieldId type in LWC to Apex

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I'm trying to implement a wire service to get data with passing schema items, but I'm getting an error that `objectName` can't be mapped to a `String`

I'm including the relevant parts below

**LWC part**

```
import getData from '@salesforce/apex/ApexTest.getData';
import OBJECT_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/Account';

...


@wire(getData, { objectName: OBJECT_NAME })
wiredPicklistValues(result) {
  ...
}
```

**Apex class**

```
global class ApexTest {

  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
  global static String getData(String objectName) {
     return 'test';
  }

}
```

When looking on LWC side, it seems to be mapping Object and Field schema to an interface called `fieldId`, but what is the appropriate object type on the Apex side?

PS: I can, of course, use JSON.stringify(...) and deserialize on Apex side, but would like to know if there is a more elegant solution to this.

Comment: Please show the getData function.

Comment: (Why are you making the Apex global? Most of the time this is unnecessary and you can use public instead)

Comment: @PhilW yep, but global is irrelevant in this issue.

Comment: @PhilW sorry, added the correct method name

Comment: Is there a reason you are actually using an import instead of simply passing the string "Account"?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, you are passing the import directly which is an object but the apex method is expecting a string. If you log the imported object on `connectedCallback`, you will get the object.

You should use `objectApiName` from the imported object which will be string.

```
@wire(getData, { objectName: OBJECT_NAME.objectApiName })
wiredPicklistValues(result) {
    console.log(result);
}
connectedCallback() {
    console.log('OBJECT_NAME => ', OBJECT_NAME);
}
```

**LOG:**

[image]

Here `OBJECT_NAME.objectApiName` will pass the object name correctly to apex and you will get return.